# To check who is running scripts in On premise farm

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

Is there any way to get detailed report of who is running CSOM/JSOM scripts in SharePoint 2013 environment and what those scripts are doing?

Answer (score 0):

CSOM is using web services so you would have to look at the IIS logs to determine the operations. But I am not sure is there way to determine what is the source. (ie. you might be using some other software for migration/moving content around that might be using the web services as well)